# Latex doesn't create bibliography anymore, also citations aren't displayed correctly

Tags: latex, overleaf, biblatex

I am working on an article in LaTeX in Overleaf. About an hour ago everything worked just fine, but now it seems that neither the bibliography at the end is created, nor do citations work - instead it just shows the reference to the citation in the final PDF (see image)

What am I doing wrong?
The bibliography is called with '\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis]', besides there is an error that there is "Empty bibliography on line", although the .bib file is also defined by '\addbibresource'

[Incorrect citation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DklqD.png)

Comment: Please make a [mre] which allows us to recreate the problem.

Comment: There are too possible reasons why this might happen: a) some error with the bibliography or b) some error unrelated to the bibliography, but because of this error, latexmk will stop after the unsuccessfully latex run and not try to build the bibliography. In both cases just showing a screenshot of the output won't help to diagnose the problem, we really must see the code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so while trying to create a small example I remembered, that I actually changed one of my sources in sources.bib. After checking it again I noticed that I had put a second comma in front of a part of that source, instead of behind it, so that it looked like this:

```
@book{ref, title={this is a title}, , author={Doe, John} year={2022}, month={Aug}}
```

So the first suggestion pretty much nailed it, I was just confused since all the warnings were shown in main.tex, none of them in sources.bib.

However, thanks for the suggestion, if I hadn't tried to create that example I wouldn't have seen it on time.